# O que é uma "pergunta bem sucedida"?

Tags: suporte

Não sou muito de fazer perguntas no *sopt*, tenho apenas seis; quatro delas estão com um total positivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, minha medalha de *curioso* está marcando apenas *3/5*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso me leva a crer que uma pergunta bem sucedida não necessariamente é uma pergunta com mais votos positivos que negativos. Sendo assim, **o que é uma *pergunta bem sucedida***? O que preciso fazer para ganhar esta medalha?

OBS: a descrição da medalha apenas diz *"Fazer uma pergunta bem recebida em 5 dias diferentes e manter um registro de pergunta positivo"*, o que não clareia muito as coisas.